# Mule - Create a custom property for use in flow

Tags: properties, mule, spring-bean

I am trying to get the OS name available in my flow so I can adjust variable depending on the operating system running.
I am new to spring beans, but so far the below will call the set function ( I see it in the log) but I need to be able to access the osName from inside my flow.

java class:

```
public class CustomVariables {
    public CustomVariables(){}

    public String osName;
    public String getOsName(){ 
        System.out.println("got value: "+ osName); 
        return osName;
    }
    public void setOsName(String name){ 
        osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("set value: "+ osName); //this prints in console on startup
    }
}
```

mule.xml:

```
<spring:beans> 
    <spring:bean class="netstockconnector.CustomVariables"> 
        <spring:property name="osName" value="{os.name}"> </spring:property>  
    </spring:bean>  
</spring:beans>
```

in flow:

```
<logger message="${osName}" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
```

This just prints to the console "${osName}" rather than "mac os x" for instance.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much simpler solution...

```
<logger message='#[System.getProperty("os.name")]' level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
```

To trigger the Mule Expression Language, the expression to evaluate should be between `#[expression to evaluate]`. By default MEL imports a set of java classes which includes java.lang.System, hence the direct utilization in the expression.